# How can I get a second field to auto populate based on the selection of the first field in Access 2013?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, database-design

I am trying to build a training record database. In our company, employees have to take a variety of different training and each certification has a different expiry timeline.

My first table lists out ALL the training along with the number of days they are valid for like so:

1. WHMIS    365 Days
2. Fall Protection   1095 Days

My second table will simply list out all the employees and each of their training and the date they took it.

For ex:

1. John Doe   WHMIS  Dec 12 2015
2. John Doe   Fall Protection   Jan 3 2014
3. Jane Doe   WHMIS  Feb 3 2016

How can I get a forth field, to automatically calculate the Expiry date, based off of the number of days the certification is valid in the first table?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's bad practice to store a calculation in a table. All of the pieces are there to make the calculation, so wherever you want it to appear is where the calculation should be done. For example if you need it on a report, do the calculation in the query used as the control source of your report. If you must, there should be a "calculated" data type which would allow you to store the calculation in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `DateAdd` function like this:

```
DateAdd("d",[NoOfdays],[TrainingDate])
```

How you will use that depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want to have it somewhere create a query that links the two tables together based on employee and add the above as a field.

If you don't want to link the tables you can use `DLookup` to read the `[NoOfDays]` field like this:

```
DLookup("[NoOfdays]","[TrainingTable]","[TrainingCourse]=" & [TrainingCourse])
```

Since you don't provide the table or field names, or whether your tables are properly structured with IDs or not that's as far as I can get you.